# Unable to execute Katalon Studio project after moved to another computer

Tags: automated-tests, katalon-studio

I have a Katalon Studio project, which is not working after I copied it to another computer.

It gives the following error message during execution:

```
SLF4J: The requested version 1.7.16 by your slf4j binding is not compatible with [1.6]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#version_mismatch for further details.
Caught: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot find test case 'Test Cases/Mycase'
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot find test case 'Test Cases/Mycase'
    at com.kms.katalon.core.testcase.TestCaseFactory.findTestCase(TestCaseFactory.java:72)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseExecutor.<init>(TestCaseExecutor.java:87)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseMain.runTestCase(TestCaseMain.java:105)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseMain.runTestCase(TestCaseMain.java:97)
    at com.kms.katalon.core.main.TestCaseMain$runTestCase$0.call(Unknown Source)
    at TempTestCase1543911985430.run(TempTestCase1543911985430.groovy:22)
```

I use the same version of Katalon Studio in both cases. Path of the framework contains only unicode characters.

Comment: Did you copy just the `.project` file? Is the `Test Cases/Mycase` file present on the filesystem of the new computer?

Comment: @MateMrše : I copied the whole directory and `Test Cases/Mycase` is present on computer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could you try the Clean up feature?
[image]

Another option is open the folder location of the project, then delete /bin and /Libs

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try using relative path for traversing the filesystem.

Instead of using 'Test Cases/Mycase', use

```
import com.kms.katalon.core.configuration.RunConfiguration
String myRelativePath = RunConfiguration.getProjectDir() + '/Test Cases/Mycase'
```

For example, instead of calling a Test Case with

```
WebUI.callTestCase(findTestCase('Test Cases/Mycase'), [:])
```

you would call it with

```
WebUI.callTestCase(findTestCase(myRelativePath), [:])
```

Comment: Is it possible to set this as default behavior? It takes too much time to replace manually all the occurences.